# Extracting a JSON from a webpage hidden behind an API in R

Tags: r, json

I'll be straightforward. I wanna get the data that appears on this website: [Liberty Shares](https://www.libertyshares.com/fund-explorer/)

So far I've tried:

- regular parsing like `read_html` and going inside nodes from the `rvest` library. This loaded the page header but not the actual table on the page.
- phantomjs to capture the page. Once again this got everything except the table on the page which is the info I want.
- curl. I got the curl command by going into Network on my browser and only looking at XHR elements. The JSON containing the data is inside the second `searchentity` element that loads. By cleaning up the curl link it failed to generate an actual JSON file saying it was malformed.

`curl "https://api.fundpress.io/fund/searchentity"-H "x-ksys-token: 92e05e6b-acca-4238-86a1-4f6dc857f319" -H "accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9" -H "user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/66.0.3359.139 Safari/537.36" -H "content-type: application/json;charset=UTF-8" -H "accept: application/json, text/plain, */*" -H "referer: https://www.libertyshares.com/fund-explorer/" -H "authority: api.fundpress.io" -H "accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br" --data-binary "{"type":"CLSS","clientCode":[""],"fundList":"us","search":[{"property":"status","values":["Active","Smart Beta","Passive"],"matchtype":"LIKE"}],"include":{"statistics":{}},"limit":"","start":0,"translate":true,"sourceCulture":"en-US","culture":"en-US"}" --compressed > liberty.html`

The only other option I can think of is using Selenium but I would like to avoid it if possible.

Comment: From that site's 'terms of use' page: "*You should not access the Site through devices or services that are designed to provide high-speed, automated, repeated access, unless such devices are approved by us.*"

Comment: Aye. While you're looking for "hidden" things, perhaps read [not so hidden things](https://www.franklintempleton.com/investor/help/terms-of-use).